# How to pay with Amazon Web Services Credits?

Tags: amazon-web-services

From a promo advertisement I received AWS credits which show up in my AWS account - but I don't know how to pay anything with those credits.

Does it work automatically if applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when I have received credits, I enter the credits onto my account and then at the end of the month AWS first uses any available credits, and then generates a charge to my credit card for the balance - so yes, in my experience they work automatically once attached to your account.